# Is there a built-in Google Sheets formula to calculate the **exact number** of fractional years between two dates?

Tags: date, google-sheets, math

I need to calculate the **exact number** of years between two dates in Google Sheets.

The most obvious methods (below) don't return the **exact number** of years.

- `number of days between the start and end` divided `365`, `354`, or `364.25`
- The [`YEARFRAC`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092989?sjid=3397409708044224040-NC) function

To get the **exact number** of years you have to add 3 sub parts:

1. The fraction of a year the `start date` covers of the start year (start date to end of year)
2. The whole number of full years between the start and end date
3. The fraction of a year the `end date` covers of the end year (first day of year to end date)

This is because the start date and/or end date could be a leap year which changes what each day in the year is as a fraction of the year.

- 2020-02-16 is a leap year and the divisor is 365
- 2021-02-16 is not a leap year and the divisor is 364

So both dates are a different fraction of the year they are.

I will explain with an example. Let's say:

- `start date` = `2020-02-16`
- `end date` = `2022-05-12`

The various formulas above give these results:

- `number of days` / `365` = `2.23561643835616`
- `number of days` / `364` = `2.24175824175824`
- `number of days` / `364.25` = `2.24021962937543`
- `YEARFRAC` with `0` for `day_count_convention` = `2.23888888888889`
- `YEARFRAC` with `1` for `day_count_convention` = `2.23322104947975`
- `YEARFRAC` with `2` for `day_count_convention` = `2.26666666666667`
- `YEARFRAC` with `3` for `day_count_convention` = `2.23561643835616`
- `YEARFRAC` with `4` for `day_count_convention` = `2.23888888888889`

But, if we break it down, we see those results are not right.
Example:

- The start year (`2020`) is a leap year with `365` days. From the start date (`2020-02-16`) to the end of that year (`2020-12-31`) there are `319` days. So that is `0.873972602739726` of a year.
- There is exactly `1` whole year between the start and end date (all of 2021)
- The end year (`2022`) is not a leap year and has `364` days. From the start of that year (`2022-01-01`) to the end date (`2022-05-12`) there are `131` days. So that is `0.35989010989011` of a year.

**If you add all 3 parts, you get `2.23386271262984`.**

If we shifted the start/end dates down exactly by one year, we'll see that the **exact number** of years between them would be different than above:

- `start date` = `2021-02-16`
- `end date` = `2023-05-12`

Then:

- `number of days` / `365` = `2.23287671232877`
- `number of days` / `364` = `2.23901098901099`
- `number of days` / `364.25` = `2.23747426218257`
- `YEARFRAC` with `0` for `day_count_convention` = `2.23888888888889` (no change)
- `YEARFRAC` with `1` for `day_count_convention` = `2.23287671232877`
- `YEARFRAC` with `2` for `day_count_convention` = `2.26388888888889`
- `YEARFRAC` with `3` for `day_count_convention` = `2.23287671232877`
- `YEARFRAC` with `4` for `day_count_convention` = `2.23888888888889` (no change)
- **exact number**:

  - start year fraction = `318` / `364` = `0.873626373626374`
  - whole years = 1
  - end year fraction = `131` / `364` = `0.35989010989011`
  - **total = `2.23351648351648`**

So, I am wondering, is there a built-in Google Sheets formula I can use to give me this **exact number** with a start/end date input? I know I can create named formulas and all that but I'm looking for a built-in, already available formula.

Comment: Just as an FYI, the proper divisor is 365.25, derived from (365 *  3 + 366) / 4. (Three 365 day years + a 366 day year divided by 4).

Comment: Regular year 365 days and leap year 366 days not 364 and 365 respectively.

Comment: @user11222393 There is a way to do it by combining a few "built in" formulas though. If that's something you're interested in, I can show you how. But it'd be good to change the question as well to reflect that distinction.

Comment: @MattKing I know about combining formulas. I was hoping for a built-in one. Oh well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, there is not a built in formula to get this answer